# wordpress website plugin for mobile device

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I have a small website created with wordpress, i only use pages as content, and as theme the "Twenty Eleven" modified by me (without a child theme).

When i access the website via PC all ok, but when i try to access via smartphone the design is all messed up.

There is a free plugin that allow to maintain the Twenty Eleven theme for PC-users, but if the user access the website via mobile device show a responsive page or another simple theme for mobile?

something simple if possibile, without change the wp code

Answer (score 1):

There is already [twenty-twelve](http://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwelve) and [twenty-thirteen](http://wordpress.org/themes/twentythirteen) theme available on `wordpress.org` and both are [responsive](http://www.responsivewebcss.com/) (mobile friendly) themes and you can modify and use them but also for `WordPress` there are some plugins available as well, you can use any one but I suggest you to use [wptouch](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wptouch/), it's free and better than others, IMO. I've used it for years for my blog but now I've managed to use a responsive theme.

If you install `wptouch` plugin then whenever a visitor will visit your site with a mobile phone, `WordPress` will use a mobile friendly theme by the help of `wptouch` plugin but if you use a responsive theme then it's always the same theme but layout will be changed to fit according to device's screen size (desktop, tablet, mobiles) and it's better
than using a plugin like `wptouch`, so if you can, use a responsive theme instead, search on Google for [free responsive themes](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=free%20responssive%20themes%20for%20wordpress&rlz=1C1KMZB_enBD539BD539&oq=free%20responssive%20themes%20for%20wordpress&aqs=chrome..69i57.11044j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) for WordPress.